# PHP Fix Needed on How to Bypass mkdir if Folder Already Exists

Tags: php, if-statement, mkdir

I have a PHP file which creates a unique directory for each user when a file is uploaded.  I would like the script to check and see if the directory already exists and if so then skip the mkdir action.  Here is my code sample:

```
<?php
$thisdir = getcwd(); 
$new_dir = "123";
$full_dir = $thisdir . "/upload/" . $new_dir;

if(mkdir($full_dir, 0777))
{
echo "Directory has been created successfully... <br>";
}
else
{
echo "Failed to create directory...";
}
?>
```

To continue this example, please assume that the folder "123" already exists.  How do I modify it for this case?  I am thinking it must be some sort of if...else statement.  Thanks for going through this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function maybe_mkdir($path, $mode) {
    if(is_dir($path)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return mkdir($path, $mode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`is_dir()`](http://www.php.net/is_dir) to find out whether the folder already exists.